# Why is the Addon XLSX not working for the following code in my system?

Tags: excel, automation, g1ant

I am trying to access two excel files that are opening using Excel Viewer but when I use the G1ANT Studio it says the files are corrupted.
Code-

```
addon xlsx version 4.101.0.0
addon core version 4.101.0.0
addon language version 4.103.0.0
xlsx.open path C:\Users\joshs\Desktop\File1.xls result ♥xlsId1
xlsx.open path C:\Users\joshs\Desktop\File2.xls result ♥xlsId2
xlsx.close id ♥xlsId2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.xlsx` format instead of `.xls` format.